# How to get the AWS RDS maximum connections from the AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there a way to get the maximum number of connections for an RDS database from the AWS API?

I know that you can get the current number of connections from the `DatabaseConnections` Cloudwatch metric, but I'm looking to get the maximum/limit of connections possible for the database.

I also know that you can get it [from within the database](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-max-connections/). For example, in Postgres, you can run:

```
postgres=> show max_connections;
```

However, I would like to get the value from outside the database.

I read in this [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections) about the `max_connections` DB instance parameter.

In most cases, the `max_connections` instance parameter is a value like this `LEAST({DBInstanceClassMemory/9531392},5000)` which depends on the `DBInstanceClassMemory` formula variable.

I read in [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ParamValuesRef.html#USER_ParamFormulas) that `DBInstanceClassMemory` can depend on several factors and is lower than the memory figures shown in [the instance class tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Summary).

Is there a way to get the `DBInstanceClassMemory` value from the API?

It looks like the AWS Console is able to get the value from outside of the database. See the red line in the graph below:

[image: DB Connections graph in the AWS Console]

Edit: I found the JavaScript function that calculates the maximum number of connections in the AWS Console. It's called `getEstimatedDefaultMaxConnections` and it basically just divides the instance class' memory (from the [instance class table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Summary)) by the default memory-per-maximum-connections value (i.e. the default formula listed [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html)). So, it ignores the fact that `DBInstanceClassMemory` will be less than the instance class' memory and it also ignores any changes you make to the `max_connections` DB instance parameter.

Is there a way for me to get that value using the API or to calculate it based on the `DBInstanceClassMemory` value (if it is available via the API)?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up calculating an **estimate** of the number of maximum connections by fetching the `max_connections` DB parameter of the database, parsing it and evaluating it.

To get an estimate of the `DBInstanceClassMemory` value, I first fetched all of the available instance types using [`describe-instance-types`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-types.html) and saved it to a file. I set `DBInstanceClassMemory` to 90% of this value to account for the memory lost to OS and RDS processes.

Then I:

1. Iterated through all of my RDS instances using [`DescribeDBInstances`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Paginator.DescribeDBInstances),
2. Fetched the DB parameters for each database using [`DescribeDBParameters`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Paginator.DescribeDBParameters) and filtered for the `max_connections` parameter.
3. Parsed the `max_connections` parameter and evaluated the function using my estimated `DBInstanceClassMemory` for the database.